# Intuition on centrifugal force regarding a particular case

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force

**Let's consider a case in which a bucket is revolving in a vertical plane with gravity acting on it**. At the highest position the gravity is acting downward but water is not going downward. Is this due to centrifugal force?

Comment: Yes it is centrifugal force. If you assume that different parts of water are almost at rest with respect to _each other_, surface tension might also help.

Comment: @proscionexium hmm nice one also I found your previous explaination more convincing

Comment: Centrifugal force is _one_ way of looking at it. But it's maybe not the most intuitive because centrifugal force only exists in a rotating coordinate system. In this case, a coordinate system where we pretend that the bucket is stationary, and the direction of gravity is whirling in circles. When you look at it from a more natural point of view, where it's the bucket that's whirling in circles, and gravity is constant, then what keeps the water in the bucket is the tension in the rope, which is caused by the motion and by the water's own _inertia._

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your frame of reference. In the non-inertial frame of the bucket, the bucket and the water in it are at rest and feel zero net force, which necessitates the inclusion of the centrifugal force to balance the downward forces of gravity and tension. In this frame, centrifugal force pushes the water up into the bucket, but it's not a "real" force as it depends entirely on your point of view.

In the inertial frame of the person swinging the bucket, the bucket and water are accelerating downward due to the combined forces of tension and gravity. In this frame, the centrifugal force doesn't even exist - there is no upward-pointing force, and the water remains in the bucket due to its own inertia. You could imagine if the bucket suddenly disappeared, the water would fly up and away in and arc - it already has upward inertia, no further force is needed to push it up. There is no "real" force pushing the water up into the bucket, very intuitively it is impossible to push water using a rope.

Answer (score 1):

Each particle of water is under the force of gravity and the force resulting from the pressure of the fluid. The vertical component of the later must balance the weight of the particle (because it remains at the same level with time).

The horizontal component is the net force, and must equal mass times acceleration, (that is the centripetal acceleration).

While it is possible to analyse the problem in the non inertial frame of the rotating bucket, with leads to a centrifugal force, it is not necessary.